# Adding traceId to kotlin reactive api with coroutines

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, opentracing

I have a spring api with Kotlin/Spring/Reactor/Coroutines
like: `suspend fun method(): String { return myService.data() }`

And I would like to add traceId to call `myService.data()`,
traceId come from call above in header (from Jaerger/Opentracing)

As solutions I found the library: implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j:1.3.9")
and when I make a call I should type the code:

```
withContext(MDCContext()) {
    logger.info("call my service")
    myService.data()
}
```

The question:
How to put traceId to the MDC coroutine context from `header` and may be need add WebFilter for getting request header and create something like request coroutine context?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With @EugeneZacharov:
found how to get context -> `Mono.deferWithContext { ctx -> Mono.just(ctx) }.awaitFirst()`

1. add WebFilter
2. copy traceId header in the filter above to ReactorContext
3. add ext fun where add MDC data when it needs:

```
suspend fun Logger.debugWithMDC(message: String) {
    if (isDebugEnabled) {
        val context = Mono.deferWithContext { ctx -> Mono.just(ctx) }.awaitFirst()
        context.copyToMdc()
        this.debug(message)
        MDC.clear()
    }
}
```

4. Profit